# Does AWS SageMaker charges for launching an instance or just for usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using AWS SageMaker studio and I need to launch a ml.p2.xlarge instance for a Training Job to run the fit() function of a model. I need to run it multiple times, and I want to know if AWS charges me for every time I launch an instance or just for the minutes I use them.

For example, if I need to run it three times, would it be cheaper to launch a ml.p2.xlarge instance once and run the training job three times in the span of an hour, or launch the instance three times in that span for 6 minutes each?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is generally to run a training jobs 3 time. This way you only pay for what you use, and there's no ideal time wasted. One thing to note is that, per job, you also pay for the overhead of loading the training container, loading data to the training container, and the duration to stop the instance. As long as this overhead is relatively small, it's worth it.
Example: (6min net training + 4min overhead) = 10min x 3 = 30min vs 60min.

Another benefit to have a job per training is separate metadata and results per job (metrics, logs, hyperparameters), comparing jobs, ability to quickly clone a job, job status. etc.

Empirically: you can run one training job, multiple results by 3.
In SageMaker Training you pay by the second ("billable seconds"). You can see this figure in the training job details in the web console (or via describe-training-job API call).